# Why am I getting "error: no match for ‘operator->*’" when the parameters on both sides look correct?

Tags: c++, templates, indirection

I'm trying to call a function from within a template function inside a template.

The call itself, however, doesn't compile, instead I get the following error:

```
/home/alexis/tmp/b.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool callback_manager<C>::call_member(F, ARGS ...) [with F = bool (main()::foo::*)(int, int, int); ARGS = {int, int, int}; C = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<main()::foo> >]’:
/home/alexis/tmp/b.cpp:43:47:   required from here  
/home/alexis/tmp/b.cpp:15:19: error: no match for ‘operator->*’ (operand types are ‘std::shared_ptr<main()::foo>’ and ‘bool (main()::foo::*)(int, int, int)’)  
        if(!(c->*func)(&args...))  
            ~~^~~~~~~~
```

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include    <memory>
#include    <vector>

template<typename C>
class callback_manager
{
public:
    template<typename F, typename ... ARGS>
    bool call_member(F func, ARGS ... args)
    {
        C callbacks(f_callbacks);
        for(auto c : callbacks)
        {
            if(!(c->*func)(args...))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

private:
    C f_callbacks;
};

int main()
{
    class foo
    {
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<foo>    pointer_t;
        typedef std::vector<pointer_t>  vector_t;

        bool the_callback(int, int, int)
        {
            return true;
        }
    };

    callback_manager<foo::vector_t> m;

    m.call_member(&foo::the_callback, 5, 13, 7);

    return 1;
}
```

Looking at the parameters, it seems to be that both are correct:

```
std::shared_ptr<main()::foo>
```

and

```
bool (main()::foo::*)(int, int, int)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that the `->*` operator doesn't work with the `std::shared_ptr<>`.

The solution is to retrieve the bare pointer like so:

```
if(!(c.get()->*func)(args...)) ...
```

It then compiles as expected.

You can also rewrite it as follow, which I think is more cryptic:

```
if(!(*c).*func)(args...)) ...
```

(i.e. the `shared_ptr::operator * ()` function returns the pointed to object held by the shared pointer, hence the `.*` operator is used in this case.)

Comment: @JaMiT Indeed, I made an edit to fix that sentence. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if(!(c->*func)(args...))
```

with

```
if(!(std::cref(func)(c, args...)))
```

to use the INVOKE machinery of C++.  Or use `std::invoke` directly.

INVOKE concept in the standard, and `std::invoke`, where designed to work with pmfs and smart pointers.

Meanwhile, `->*` isn't overloaded by smart pointers.  So direct use like that won't work.

As a side benefit, now a non member function can be passed in as the func.

Comment: In my full implementation, `c` can be a _direct function_ (could be an `std::bind()`) or an object. Now I'm wondering whether this would work with those two without me having to create a specialization.

Comment: @alexis if c is a function, what is func?  Or is it another method than `call_member`?  Sure, `call(args...)` can just `std::invoke(c,args...)`; the call on or call member moves one of the args before `c`.